# PHP Poll  system to each article

Tags: php

the Poll  system have two part(the user cast poll part and the result show part) the cast poll part has two buttons. which is up and down. the result show part using five star to show the average result which casted by all the vistors. say concisely: the poll system has two button, on is up, another is down. when a vistor polls up/down. it will show the  average poll result of the article. which is displayed by five stars.

Comment: wow, that's the worst attempt at a question I have seen in a while

Comment: why? the effect is hard to get?

Comment: Yes, it is hard to understand what you're after.  Can you try to explain what you're trying to do, and what you've tried so far?

Comment: reads like it was translated by machine, which is rarely good enough for a common conversation let alone a technical question; where precision is vital for meaning.

Answer (score 1):

You need at least Javascript for that. To update the database dynamically when a button is pressed, you need some AJAX code.

Glance over http://jquery.com/ There are tons of examples, plugins, discussion there.